# Methods to install X11 on Lion

Tags: macos, x11

My girlfriend recently ordered a MacBook Pro with Lion installed. For an online class she needs GIMP which depends on X11. What are my options to get it? Is there any Apple-sanctioned way to do the install? Would there be any downside to using the SL DVD from my machine? Or should I just install XQuartz?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a matter of fact Lion DOES ship with X11. There were many doubts, and many believed it wouldn't, but it does.

Source: me. Ive got `xeyes` running on my Lion iMac right now. :)

Another Source: Apple. http://www.apple.com/macosx/apps/all.html#x11

Comment: Okay, thanks! No wonder I couldn't find install instructions.

Comment: This build of GIMP is the one recommended by gimp.org for use on a Mac. It works fine for me on Lion: http://gimp.lisanet.de/Website/News/News.html

Comment: @NReilingh: you mean 2.6.11 for Leopard but from the site you mention? Can you post a direct link for GIMP that works for you on Lion?

Comment: The build mentioned by @NReilingh also works for me. The build is 2.6.11 for Leopard.

Comment: @delirius for Lion, you will want the build that is for Snow Leopard. Version 2.6.11 is current. Download page is here: http://gimp.lisanet.de/Website/Download.html

Answer (score 0):

I've found [this post](http://www.webnapps.co.uk/how-to/how-to-install-gimp-on-mac-lion) is very helpful to install GIMP on Mac OS X Lion:

> Just go to http://gimp.lisanet.de/Website/Download.html and download the GIMP 2.6.11 for Leopard version on your Lion. I’ve tried the Snow leopard and Tiger version but that doesn’t work for me.